# Convert NEC antenna file to .out-file for Wattwächter

Tags: antenna, wire-antenna, antenna-modeling

I've just wrote a NEC Antenna file of my longwire with xnec2c on Ubuntu. To calculate protection distance with [Wattwächter](https://emf3.bundesnetzagentur.de/wattw%C3%A4chter.html), I need an .out-file. Protection distance means the safety distance for human where the limits for electric field strength were kept as described in ICNIRP DIN VDE 0848 ([overview table](https://www.darc.de/fileadmin/filemounts/referate/ajw/Onlinelehrgang/a19/Tabelle_Personenschutz.gif)).

How do I generate/convert?

Comment: Hello Tobias, and welcome to this site! Kindly edit your question to explain what you mean by "*protection* distance".

Comment: @MikeWaters: Hi Mike, thanks for your comment. Now I tried to be more specific

Comment: That program is pretty interesting! Didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I'm using the software 4nec2 (with wine) with the description from [DL6GL](http://dl6gl.de/anzeige-nach-bemfv/1-antennenmodellierung-mit-4nec2). With this software you can generate the .out files. I hope to succeed.